# Databinding and DataContext in WPF Desktop application with multiple views using UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I am working on my first project with WPF and as practice, have created an application that has a menu bar with two buttons on the side which are used to change the display two different views on the grid to its right. I am using the MVVM pattern. Using the ICommand interface, I am able to change the view in the grid using usercontrols for the two views from the menu bar buttons. The application is as follows:

The menu bar has buttons named View 1 and View 2, clicking any of them will open up the relevant view in the usercontrol. At startup a "defaultview" is displayed. The default view has a button which can also be used to move to View 1. Below is what I am stuck at:

1. I have a button in View 1 to change the display to View 2 (it calls the same command I made in the App View Model but even though it changes the variable value to which the sidegrid is bound too, the view displayed doesnt change).
2. I want to pass data (tried with First Name) from View 1 to View 2 but I cant get binding to work.

Can someone guide me or link me to examples or material that discuss this?

App View Model

```
using DataBindingAndViewsTestProject.Views;
using Hotel_Management_Project_WPF.Utilities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DataBindingAndViewsTestProject.ViewModels
{
    public class AppVM : ObservableObject
    {

        //Create a property that controls current view


        private object _currentView;
        public object CurrentView
        {
            get { return _currentView; }
            set { OnPropertyChanged(ref _currentView, value);
            }
        }



        //Instantiate the relaycommands, we will need to instantiate relaycommand objects for every command we need to perform. 
        //This means that we will need to do this for preses of all buttons
        public RelayCommand View1ButtonCommand { get; private set; }
        public RelayCommand View2ButtonCommand { get; private set; }


        public AppVM()
        {
            CurrentView = new DefaultVM();
            View1ButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(ShowView1, AlwaysTrueCommand);
            View2ButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(ShowView2, AlwaysTrueCommand);

        }



        public void ShowView1(object dummy)
        {
            CurrentView = new View1();

        }

        public void ShowView2(object dummy)
        {
            CurrentView = new View2();
        }


        public bool AlwaysTrueCommand(object dummy)
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Main Window.xaml

```
      <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="600"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
            <Button x:Name="view1Button" Content="Go to View 1" Margin="10" Command="{Binding View1ButtonCommand}"></Button>
            <Button x:Name="view2Button" Content="Go to View 2" Margin="10" Command="{Binding View2ButtonCommand}"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}"></ContentControl>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

View1.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="DataBindingAndViewsTestProject.Views.View1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataBindingAndViewsTestProject.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DataBindingAndViewsTestProject.ViewModels">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:AppVM x:Name="AppVMinView1" x:Key="AppVMinView1"></vm:AppVM>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:View1VM></vm:View1VM>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid Background="Aqua">
        <StackPanel Margin="100">
            <TextBlock Text="First Name"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="firstNameTextBoxView1" Text="{Binding View1InfoClass.FirstName, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock Text="Last Name"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="lastNameTextBoxView1" Text="{Binding View1InfoClass.LastName, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock Text="Random Useless Number" ></TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="randomUselessNumberView1" Text="{Binding View1InfoClass.Number, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>

            <TextBlock Text="First Name Entered"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding View1InfoClass.FirstName}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="Last Name Entered" ></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding View1InfoClass.LastName}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="Random Useless Number Entered"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding View1InfoClass.Number}"></TextBlock>

            <Button DataContext="{StaticResource AppVMinView1}" Content="Go to view2" Height="20" Width="70" Command="{Binding View2ButtonCommand}" />



        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

View2.xaml

```
    <UserControl x:Class="DataBindingAndViewsTestProject.Views.View2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataBindingAndViewsTestProject.Views"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DataBindingAndViewsTestProject.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:View1VM x:Key="View1VMInView2" x:Name="View1VMInView2"></vm:View1VM>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:View2VM></vm:View2VM>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid Background="Beige">
        <StackPanel Margin="100">
            <TextBlock Text="First Name"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="firstNameTextBoxView2" Text="{Binding View2InfoClass.FirstName, Mode=OneWayToSource,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock Text="Last Name"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="lastNameTextBoxView2" Text="{Binding View2InfoClass.LastName, Mode=OneWayToSource,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock Text="Random Useless Number"></TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="randomUselessNumberView2" Text="{Binding View2InfoClass.Number, Mode=OneWayToSource,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock Text="First Name Entered"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock  DataContext="View1InView2" Text="{Binding View1InfoClass.FirstName}" ></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="Last Name Entered"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="Random Useless Number Entered"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock  ></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Model (if relevant)

```
  public class InfoClass:ObservableObject
    {
        private string _firstName;

        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _firstName; }
            set {
                OnPropertyChanged(ref _firstName, value);
                 }
        }

        private string _lastName;

        public string LastName
        {
            get { return _lastName; }
            set { OnPropertyChanged(ref _lastName, value); }
        }

        private int _number;

        public int Number
        {
            get { return _number; }
            set { OnPropertyChanged(ref _number, value); }
        }

    }
```

Comment: You should try to pass CommandParameter on your  `<Button DataContext="{StaticResource AppVMinView1}" Command="... "CommandParameter="{Binding ...} ..."` to pass data from XAML to VM.

When you create new View `CurrentView = new View2(...);` you can pass data through a constructor.

Comment: Cool! Thank you. I will do this :)